# Disable ValidateRequest for a specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, validate-request

Friends I am in trouble and need your help.

For database management in the admin section of my website I have few text fields where I would like to input data along with HTML tags.
As soon as i add any HTML tag such as < BR /> the SQLDATASOURCE Update gives an error "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Already tried **ValidateRequest="false"** but it didnt work
Can not use AJAX Editor due to space issue.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

If i use **httpRuntime requestValidationMode** then it disable validation on the whole website making it open for hackers.

Friends how can i disable **ValidateRequest** only for specific page(s) in the admin section only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net Framework 4.0, if you set **requestValidationMode="2.0"** in web.config, it doesn't means the whole site be will disabled for validation. It just changed back to 2.0 validation mode which validate only for .aspx pages. So you can apply **validateRequest** page driective attribute to false for the pages you want to disable after setting to 2.0 mode.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx): *requestValidationMode=2.0. Request validation is enabled only for pages, not for all HTTP requests. In addition, the request validation settings of the pages element (if any) in the configuration file or of the **@ Page directive in an individual page are used to determine which page requests to validate**.*

Answer (score 2):

You can set an attribute on your controller methods or controller to disable the validationRequest

```
[ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("validateRequest", DefaultValue= false)]
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more please how to do so

Comment: I think I described the usage a little bit off... (sometimes my english hits the bottom) so what I wanted to say is you can set the validateRequest for specified properties like this:

`[ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("validateRequest", DefaultValue = false)]
        public string WantedValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `ValidateRequest="false"` in your page directive

Comment: i already have ValidateRequest="false" there  here is the code <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/Master/MasterAdmin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PhoneDataAdd.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_PhoneDataAdd" ValidateRequest="false" %>